# Issue with POST request to SendGrid using React and Express

Tags: javascript, typescript, forms, post, request

I'm encountering an error while attempting to send a POST request using the SendGrid module in my React and Express application. The goal is to enable users to input their name, email, and message through a contact form, and have that information sent to ****@gmail.com. However, when I click the send button, the POST request fails with the following error:

```
xhr.js:210 POST http://localhost:3000/send-email 404 (Not Found)
```

To provide more context, here's the relevant code snippet from my contact form component, card.tsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import cardcss from "./Card.module.css";
import axios from "axios";

interface CardProps {
  imageUrl: string;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}

function Card(props: CardProps) {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const nameInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const emailInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const messageInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (messageInputRef.current) {
      messageInputRef.current.focus();
      messageInputRef.current.setSelectionRange(0, 0);

      // Delay setting the cursor position
      setTimeout(() => {
        messageInputRef.current?.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
      }, 0);
    }
  }, []);

  const handleFocus = (event: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    event.target.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
  };

  const submitHandler = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (
      nameInputRef.current &&
      emailInputRef.current &&
      messageInputRef.current
    ) {
      const nameInput = nameInputRef.current.value;
      const emailInput = emailInputRef.current.value;
      const messageInput = messageInputRef.current.value;

      const contactData = {
        Name: nameInput,
        Email: emailInput,
        Message: messageInput,
      };
      console.log(contactData);

      axios
        .post("http://localhost:3000/send-email", contactData)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("Received email request");
          // Handle success response
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          // Handle error response
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={cardcss.cardcontainer}>
      <div className={cardcss.imagecontainer}>
        <img src={props.imageUrl} alt="" />
      </div>

      <div className={cardcss.cardtitle}>
        <h3>{props.title}</h3>
      </div>

      <div className={cardcss.cardbody}>
        <p>{props.body}</p>

        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <div>
            <label className={cardcss.namelabel} htmlFor="name">
              Name:
            </label>
            <input
              className={cardcss.nameinput}
              type="text"
              id="name"
              name="name"
              ref={nameInputRef}
            />
          </div>

          <div className={cardcss.emailcontainer}>
            <label className={cardcss.emaillabel} htmlFor="email">
              Email:
            </label>
            <input
              className={cardcss.emailinput}
              type="text"
              id="email"
              name="email"
              ref={emailInputRef}
            />
          </div>

          <div className={cardcss.messagecontainer}>
            <label className={cardcss.messagelabel} htmlFor="message">
              Message:
            </label>
            <input
              ref={messageInputRef}
              className={cardcss.messageinput}
              type="text"
              id="message"
              name="message"
              value={message}
              onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
              onFocus={handleFocus}
            />

            <button className={cardcss.sendbutton} type="submit">
              Send
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

On the server-side, I have the following code in server.js to handle the POST request:

```
const express = require("express");
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
const { resolve } = require("path-browserify");

// Set up SendGrid API key
sgMail.setApiKey(
  "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"
);

// Create Express app
const app = express();

// Middleware to parse JSON requests
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello, server!");
});
// Route to handle sending emails
app.post("/send-email", (req, res) => {
  const { Name, Email, Message, submitbutton } = req.body;

  const msg = {
    to: "paristiffany12@gmail.com",
    from: "paristiffany12@gmail.com",
    subject: "Example Subject",
    text: `Name: ${Name}\nEmail: ${Email}\nMessage: ${Message}\nSubmit Button: ${submitbutton}`,
    html: `<p>Name: ${Name}</p><p>Email: ${Email}</p><p>Message: ${Message}</p><p>Submit Button: ${submitbutton}</p>`,
  };

  sgMail
    .send(msg)
    .then(() => {
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Email sent successfully" });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error.toString());
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to send email" });
    });
});

// Set up fallback for path module
resolve.fallback = { path: require.resolve("path-browserify") };

// Start the server
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

I have verified that the contactData object contains the correct values for name, email, and message by logging it to the console before making the POST request.

I'm seeking assistance in understanding why I'm encountering this POST request error and how I can resolve it. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is your server running and listening on port 3000 ?

Comment: Hi, yes my server is running and listening on port 3000

Comment: Hi, yes my server is running and listening on port 3000